# Parameterized ZSH alias

Tags: command-line, zsh

Hello I'm trying to make an alias in zsh for the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances delete CONTAINER_NAME --zone=x --quiet
```

How can I make an alias that would fit my parameter in the CONTAINER_NAME ?

Monterey 12.2

Comment: Might be better to define a shell function for this.

Comment: You don't. An alias does not take parameters.

Answer (score 3):

`zsh` supports functions, so you can put the following into the appropriate startup file

```
function gcloud_delete() {
    gcloud compute instances delete "$1" --zone=x --quiet
}
```

and then (after sourcing that file) run

```
gcloud_delete CONTAINER
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ~/.zshrc, reload it with `. ~/.zshrc` and off you go (with `gcdc MY_CONTAINER`):

```
alias gcdc='(){ gcloud compute instances delete $1 --zone=x --quiet ; }'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at oh-my-zsh project.

You have a plugin called *aliases*. With it, you're able to define aliases using arguments.

To edit the aliases file:
`code ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/aliases/aliases.plugin.zsh`

In that file you can create an alias like this:

> gcInstanceDelete="gcloud compute instances delete $1 --zone=x --quiet"

And call the alias with:
`gcInstanceDelete CONTAINER_NAME`

Comment: How do you find documentation on that plugin. ie a URL so that you can see what it does before installing.